# SSRS Expression convert field to HH:MM:SS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, shoretel

I am working on converting a Variable field to HH:MM:SS to display in a grid view. I am not sure how to write the expression. Can anyone assist?

**Expression behind the variable is:**

```
=Avg(Cdbl(IIF((Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7), IIF ((Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7), (Fields!DurationSeconds.Value) , (0)), 0)), "Group1")
```

Expression Variable is:

```
Variables!RACallsAbandonedAvPerGr3.Value
```

I am trying to convert to variable to HH:MM:SS an expression format in a grid field to display avg abandoned time.
**Example:**
Average Abandoned time
00:01:20

Thanks,

Comment: What is your current time represented in? Seconds?

Comment: yes seconds. i used the following expression.=Avg(Cdbl(IIF((Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7), IIF ((Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7), (Format(DateAdd("h", "m", "s" Fields!Duration.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")) , (0)), 0)), "Group1")

Comment: i used duration instead of durtionseconds and it still had an issue.

Comment: I have modified my answer a bit, but you have to pick a duration type you want to represent (can only be one: H or M or S) Hour, Minutes, Seconds

Comment: Ok, this partially worked, thank you.  One question though. Is there a way to pick up the minute and second? The outcome could be 00:01:30.

Comment: If you look at xan's responce on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332217/how-to-display-a-time-span-of-seconds-in-hhmmss-format-in-reporting-services  You can use some custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use X as your base time (the time you are converting) you can do the following:

`Format(DateAdd("x", Variables!RACallsAbandonedAvPerGr3.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")`

Just be sure to substitute your x for: 
Hours = "h"
or 
Minutes = "m" 
or
Seconds = "s".

You have to pick one of the types.